# Group data on the basis of presence of attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

these are my models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :vendor
end

class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Scenario is Message may or may not have vendor_id.
What I want to do is, have a method `classified_messages` which will get the messages but categorized into two: messages that has vendor, and messages that do not have a vendor as shown below:

```
user = User.first
user.classified_messages
# Expected
{
  general: [], # array of messages which do not have vendor_id
  specific: [] # array of messages which has vendor_id
}
```

What I tried and didn't work:

```
user.messages.group_by{ |m| m.vendor_id.present? ? 'specific' : 'general' }
```

How can I achieve this using group_by? or cannot be achieved using group_by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was the result?  It works for me with a simple split on the even/oddness of the id field.

```
> ApiUser.all.group_by{|e| e.id.even? ? :even : :odd}.keys
=> [:even, :odd]
> ApiUser.all.group_by{|e| e.id.even? ? :even : :odd}.values.map(&:size)
=> [2, 4]
```

Comment: My bad. It's a silly mistake, I was checking on messages that did not had vendor_id and I was expecting both. But, thanks for pointing out. I was digging this since 2 hrs.  Accepting your answer as correct.